# Extend the width MDL input when typing

Tags: javascript, css, material-design-lite

I have standard mdl textfield input

```
  <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="search">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="search"></label>
    </div>
```

[image]

How to extend the width of `mdl-textfield__input` when typing?

[image]

Comment: Look at here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/materialdesignlite/materialdesignlite_textfields.htm

Comment: @jonghyonlee the one I am using called Expandable but it is not expanding when you typing it is expanding when you clicking on search example on url u provided.

Comment: in this code, expanding  execute for mdl-textfield__expandable-holder class. If you not define mdl-textfield__expandable-holder class to parent, it isn't expand. in words,mdl-textfield__input class allows input tag to apply material css and jquery.